# Change date language in a client version of craft

Tags: datetime, date, language

I've installed a client version of craft. Apparently this is set in my local language (Dutch). First question is if that is something you can set to another language or must I install a Pro version for that? (Dutch is fine, but just would like to know)

Now, while the CP is in Dutch, if I parse the month, it is in English:

```
{{ entry.postDate.format('F') }}
```

So how can that be set in Dutch as well?

Comment: noregt, I think all of your question's topics are covered by that other Q/A. Leave a comment there if something is not clear to you, ok?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in the twig docs, this appears to work:

```
{{ entry.postDate|date("F") }}
```

This uses the local date setup instead of the US setup

Still odd, that the standard language from the CP is not used?